# Clustering and Predicting Subclasses

Tags: clustering

I am trying to work on a  clustering problem where I actually know the sublcass.

Suppose I am trying to predict cluster patients a group of people into male and female where I actually know the label male and female but I take it I don't know

Suppose my clustering method produces subclasses label 1 and 2. Is there a quick method of how to assign which labels 1 and 2 to male or female to maximize my prediction accuracy? Obvious in this case since there are only two cases it is trivial but when the number of subclasses gets big it, trying all the possible combinations can be very time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing time consuming here, compared to the cost of clustering the data.

You can find the most common label per cluster in O(n) with tiny constant factors, that is as fast as it will get.

Answer (score 0):

The automatic cluster assignment problem you're looking for can be solved by the *clustering error*, or *maximum match*, measure. It tries to find the best label assignment to the found clusters (even when you have found less/more clusters than the correct number of labels).

Take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqY1Yf7HjVY&index=49&list=LLSeEsi1AFeUT7oT5NVE4tvQ) and [this scientific paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1637417/).